# Ghostly Pojo method

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple hibernate entity.

but every time when I get a particular value that is previously set with value.. it will return null.

when i set into the code.. and see what the GETVALUE does.. the most scary thing is..

it will go into another METHOD(GET)! damn when I'm typing about this my hair is standing..

does anyone have any simple explanation for this?

The below is just a simple example.. for example when it getName().. it will go into getAge() .. totally shocking

```
public class SimplePojo {

    @Id
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private  String age;

    @Column(name = "GENDER", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String gender;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

Comment: there may be some problem with your tale column mapping in your hbm. can u share ur hbm file?

Answer (score 2):

There's no *ghostly pojo*. Hibernate is using a proxy object behind the scenes that will connect to your database for lazy field initialization of this object.

If you want to disable this, just change the HBM configuration that loads this object from `lazy="true"` to `lazy="false"`. Note that by doing this, Hibernate will load all the data and associations in first cache level thus hitting your application memory.

More info:

- [Hibernate Documentation: Chapter 4. Persistent Classes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.htm)

Comment: is not a mapped object =x is just a simple @COLUMN

Comment: @user4127 make sure that this field is not configured to be lazy loaded. It will be better if you update your question content and show the real POJO and its configuration. By the way, the lazy loading can be in another POJO that lazy loads this `SimplePojo`, probably in a `bag` or another structure.